# I am 21 years old and I wish to invest my $15.000 of savings but don't know how to

Tags: investing, savings, starting-out-investing, profitability

I have been working for a while now and I realized that I have saved a moderated sum of money that I wish to invest and eventually make it grow.

But, it happens that I am new to investment. I currently have no debt what-so-ever, and I currently have got all my basic life needs satisfied.

How can I invest my money in a smart and responsible way?

Comment: What is your goal for the money?

Comment: My goal for the money is simple. To increase its total ammount by investing in something that I know it can be promising

Comment: I phrased my question incorrectly: what is the future purpose of the money?  (Car, education, house/family, retirement, etc.)  This question is important because it goes a long way towards deciding where you put the money.

Comment: That's a good question. I currently have everything I need, except for my own house. The future purpose of the money is into something that I know I can profit from, with the ultimate goal of buying a house for myself in order to fully claim my independence. For example, starting at the age of 17, I started trading a lot of used cars and selling things I usually found abandoned and ever since, I have kinda learned the art of trade and profit.

Comment: I have though about such options, and Certificates of Deposit are indeed safe, but in my country, it's like having money retained for 1 or 2 years, for a mere 1% or below return after that period of time... and I'm honestly not interested in such poor returns. Setting up my own thing would include to pay taxes and pay for other stuff and eventually people... and that's a very heavy and risky burden. I am more interested in what some people have mentioned as, making money work.